# Can all transitive verbs take to-infinitive clauses?

Tags: infinitives, clauses

> Yet it would be your duty to bear it, if you could not avoid it: it
>   is weak and silly to say you cannot bear what it is **your fate to be
>   required to bear**. — *Jane Eyre*

It seems ‘your fate to be required to bear’ is a to-infinitive clause (or non-finite-clause by Bas Aarts: “They would hate [Jim to sell his boat].”) and the object of *cannot bear*; *what it is* means ‘whatever it is’ and can be put in brackets.

Can all transitive verbs take the clauses as their objects?

If you see the object of *cannot bear* as what-clause, would you let me know just the last question?

Comment: Do all transitive bears have pause, ... I meant, paws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there was a mistake in choosing the segment to boldface.
"*Your fate to be required to bear"* is not itself a constituent. It's just a part of a constituent.

> (Parenthetically, the answer to the presenting question is ***No***; only **some** verbs -- transitive **and** intransitive, because infinitives can be subjects, too -- can take infinitive complements. Of course there are other kinds of infinitives, too, but this answer is already too long.)

The smallest constituent that contains this string -- and it still needs quite a lot of untangling, because it's been done plenty of things to -- is

- *what it is your fate to be required to bear*

the direct object of the higher *bear*.

This construction is an embedded question [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html). The introductory *what* gets "moved"  by Question Formation from (i.e, it appears somewhere other than) its normal position in the clause, which would be after the lower *bear* as its direct object. 
 (in the dissection that follows, I mark items that are moved or deleted as `code`)

- *it is your fate to be required to bear `what`*

That, in turn, has been Extraposed from

- *`for you` to be required to bear `what` is your fate*

That is, the subject of *is your fate* is an infinitive clause:

- *`for you` to be required to bear `what`*

*You* is the subject of the infinitive verb *be required*.

> Subjects are marked with *for* in an infinitive, and both `for` and `you` get deleted here, because infinitive subjects normally are deleted, either because they're indefinite and apply to everybody, or -- as in this case -- because they're predictable from elsewhere in the context, and *you* gets mentioned in *your duty*.

This clause, too, has been done things to. It's a Passive clause, so `you` has been "moved" by Passive from its position as the object of *require*. (What was the subject? Who knows? That's what `indef` means.)

- *`for indef` to require `you` to bear `what`*

with another `you` as the object (or *requiree*) of the requirement.

And we're not done yet. There's still **another** infinitive, the lower *bear*, which is intended to be in parallel with the upper *bear*, and to reinforce the message.

- *`for you` to bear `what`*

It has a subject `you`, in fact the same `you` that got "moved" [by B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) to be the object `you` in the *require* clause above.

This whole process is what I meant in [this handout](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf) by "unwinding" syntactic rules, constructions, or alternations.

Now I have to go wash my hands.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is introduced in part in the e-book *[Catenatives or complex vp: The debate about specific verbs in English](http://www.grin.com/en/e-book/52296/catenatives-or-complex-vp-the-debate-about-specific-verbs-in-english)* :

> Most linguists agree that there is a particular feature of certain verbs like e.g. want, begin, try or seem that sets them apart from other verbs: their ability to be combined into chains of verbs, to 'catenate' (Lat.catena:chain).

Sadly, not all the content is accessible; further treatment (including alternative, and preferred, analyses of these structures) can be found in *[English and the Good Grammarian](http://www.uam.es/proyectosinv/woslac/Amaya/Mendikoetxea%20%282003%29%20English%20and%20the%20Good%20Gramarian.pdf)* (section 3.2 ff). Section 3.3.3 (8) introduces 'complex catenation' (where the verb accepts / needs a noun group between the first verb and the infinitive, to-infinitive, -ing form ...).

There are relatively few verbs that catenate, in either simple or complex (some do both) constructions. (I have a list of 272.)

Comment: These are generally called "small verbs" by some linguists.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I adore Jane Eyre, the phrasing seems entirely redundant. *What is your fate to be required to bear..* could easily have been communicated "what is your fate to bear." Logically, if your fate is that which is destined and unavoidable, and one is already destined to bear X or Y; is it really necessary that one's fate, must further "require one" to bear X or Y? That's like telling someone that they have no choice but to find it necessary or dutiful to endure their struggles! If one has no choice in a matter, then every other 'requirement' or sentiment is quite useless.